# How to handle the following test case for the SPOJ-Tourist using recursion?

Tags: dynamic-programming

Can anyone suggest how to handle  the following case for the SPOJ-Tourist problem( http://www.spoj.com/problems/TOURIST/ )?

The case is:

```
5 5 
.**** 
*###* 
*.*.* 
.#### 
.*.*.
```

My implementation is similar to this sample code( mentioned in [How to solve this by recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31994668/how-to-solve-this-by-recursion) )

```
const int N 100+5
vector<string> board;

int dp[N][N][N];  // initialize with -1

int calc(int x1, int y1, int  x2) {
    int n=board.size(), m=board[0].size();
    int y2=x1+y1-x2;
    if(x1>=n || x2>=n || y1>=m || y2>=m) return 0;   // out of range
    if(board[x1][y1]=='#' || board[x2][y2]=='#') return 0;  // path blocked so its an invalid move
    if(dp[x1][y1][x2]!=-1) return dp[x1][y1][x2];  // avoid recalculation
    int res=0;
    if(board[x1][y1]=='*') res++;
    if(board[x2][y2]=='*') res++;
    if(board[x1][y1]=='*' && x1==x2 && y1==y2) res=1;  // both tourist on same spot
    int r=calc(x1+1, y1, x2);        // first tourist down second tourist right
    r=max(r, calc(x1+1, y1, x2+1));  // first tourist down second tourist down
    r=max(r, calc(x1, y1+1, x2));    // first tourist right second tourist right
    r=max(r, calc(x1, y1+1, x2+1));  // first tourist right second tourist down
    res+=r;
    dp[x1][y1][x2]=res;  // memoize
    return res;
}
```

But I guess this won't work for the above case.
The ans should be 4 but it is giving 8 as output.

Comment: I have implemented it in C++ following the idea mentioned in the above code.

Comment: your call this: calc(x1+1, y1, x2+1) seems to be culprit. Because both your +1 to x1 & x2 will cancel out & y2 will be same as previous y2. Your condition if(dp[x1][y1][x2]!=-1) return dp[x1][y1][x2]; prevents infinite loop but results in counting value of each position again.

Answer (score 0):

Your call this:

> calc(x1+1, y1, x2+1)

seems to be culprit. Because both your `+1` to `x1` & `x2` will cancel out & `y2` will be same as previous `y2`. Your condition

> if(dp[x1][y1][x2]!=-1) return dp[x1][y1][x2];

prevents infinite loop but results in counting value of each position again.

One simple solution that came is: instead of sending `(x1+1, y1, x2+1)` etc, send `(x1,y1,x2)` and one control information say `0(1R-2R),1(1R-2D),2(1D-2R),3(1D-2D)`. And then based on control information, calculate new pair of `(x1, y1)` & `(x2,y2)`